# Resource type for using stackdriver logger in python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, monitoring, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm currently using stackdriver for cloud logging my python code. I am trying to setup notifications which requires me to specify a resource type but I can't find which resource type I am using?

Comment: More details and include your code. Unless you have set up something specify your application logs will go to Global and not to specific resources. Find your logs in the Stackdriver Console and see what is specified.

Comment: Fixed it - had to set resource type to global

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by going to the resources menu on the left panel of the Stackdriver interface, and click on Metrics Explorer. Once you are in metrics explorer you can start by typing Global, and then scroll up until you see global. From there click on Global under Resource types. This will narrow down the metrics for you to search. Once you find the resource you are trying to monitor, you can then note it and create an alert for it. For more information about Python and Stackdriver check out this [link](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setup/python).

Answer (score 0):

The resource type will depend on where your code is running.  For example, if you're running on a VM in GCE, the resource type will be "gce_instance".  If it's running in a container in GKE, it'll be "k8s_container", and etc. If you're running the code outside of GCP, it may be logged under the "global" resource.